# subMenu in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu

I want to attach a menu item on click of which a sub menu opens.

I am able to get the output but my menu item always appears in the overflow menu. With some research I found out that setShowAsAction can be used to make it visible on the Action Bar but I can't set them for subMenu item.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //(this is valid) menu.add("File").setShowAsAction(2);
        SubMenu sm = menu.addSubMenu("File");
        //(can't do this) sm.setShowAsAction(2);
        sm.add("Open");
        sm.add("Close");        
        return true;       
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sm.getItem()` to get the actual `MenuItem` for the submenu. You can then call `setShowAsAction()` on that.